# Dropdown menu in Umbraco Cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco

This is my Master layout page. I am generating the dynamic menu, but clicking the dropdown does not show any items. What am I doing wrong?

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Master>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>@Umbraco.Field("siteTitle")</title>
        <meta name="description" content="@Umbraco.Field("metaDescription", recursive: true)">
        <meta name="keyword" content="@Umbraco.Field("metaKeywords", recursive: true)">
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
```

This is the start of the navigation section.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      @{ IPublishedContent root = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1); }
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">     
        <li class="@((Model.Content.Name == root.Name) ? "active" : null)">
            <a href="/">@root.Name</a></li>
        </li>
        @foreach (IPublishedContent menuItem in root.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible())) {
            <li class="@((menuItem.Name == Model.Content.Name) ? "active" : null)">
                <a href="@menuItem.Url">@menuItem.Name</a>
            </li>
        }
```

This is where the code starts to not work.

```
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href='@Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "projectsMain")'>Our Proj<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @{
              IQueryable projectsDropdown =
                Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1)
                .Children
                .Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "projectsMain")
                .First()
                .Children
                .Where("Visible")
                .OrderBy("Name");

            }
            @foreach(IPublishedContent project in projectsDropdown){
                                var prevalue = project.GetPropertyValue<int>("projectStatus");
                                if(Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString(prevalue) == "Completed"){
                                    <li><a href="@project.Url">@project.Name</a></li>
                                }
                            }
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

        @RenderBody();

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried debugging your way through? Have you checked the generated HTML source to see if there actually are items in the dropdown-menu ul?

Which Umbraco version are you using? Looks like 7.x - so there are much easier ways to do some of what you do. Like @CurrentPage.Site() to get root node.

You are including both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js, that might mess things up, as well as including what looks like two versions of jQuery?

Also, you are including (the jquery-2.2.0.js) jQuery after bootstrap.js, that might also cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was the bootstrap and the jquery files which caused the problem!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :-)